# Google Nest Hello Streaming URL Not Working

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, rtsp, nest-device-access

I am using the following API by Google, https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-live-stream

I have successfully been able to see a list of my devices and relevant information. I also am able to make a successful `GenerateRtspStream` request. I receive the following response as documented on their API

```
{
  "results" : {
    "streamUrls" : {
      "rtsp_url" : "rtsps://someurl.com/CjY5Y3VKaTZwR3o4Y19YbTVfMF...?auth=g.0.streamingToken"
    },
    "streamExtensionToken" : "CjY5Y3VKaTZwR3o4Y19YbTVfMF...",
    "streamToken" : "g.0.streamingToken",
    "expiresAt" : "2018-01-04T18:30:00.000Z"
  }
}
```

The problem however is I am unable to access the video feed. I have tried using things like VLC player and Pot Player to view the live feed, but they say that URL does not exist. I have also tried using `OpenCV` in `python` to try and access the live-feed as well and it also does not work ( I have tested `opencv` on local files and they work just fine ).

Am I doing something wrong with `rtsps` urls? How do I access the live-feed, either in `python` or some third-party application like `VLC Player`

Here is some examples of what I have already tried doing:

```
import cv2 as cv
x = cv.VideoCapture(STREAM_URL)
# ret is False --- it works on local files as it returns True and I am able to view the media 
ret, img = x.read()
```

Here is the attempt using Pot Player/VLC

[image]

My goal is to do processing on this video-feed/image in python, so ideally my solution would be using `opencv` or something along those lines. I was mainly using `VLC` and other players to debug the issue with this url first.

***UPDATE***

I have tested using the following public link
rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov
:

```
MYURL = "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"
MYURL = STREAM_URL
import cv2 as cv
x = cv.VideoCapture(MYURL)
while(True):
    ret, img = x.read()
    if not ret:
        print('URL not working')
        break
    cv.imshow('frame', img)
    cv.waitKey(1)
```

And it works perfectly with `opencv` as well as `Pot Player`. So maybe the issue is with the Google Devices Access API? The URL they provide may not be correct? Or am I missing something here?

Maybe it has to do with the `rtsps` URL vs `rtsp`? How can I fix that?

Comment: Dont you know rtsp link of your webcam? Which link are u using for web browser interface ?

Comment: I am using the rtsps link that the google api provides. My problem seems to be that opencv, VLC, and PotPlayer all do not support rtsps. But only rtsp. 

I found a solution where using ffmpeg works. I guess I’ll have to use ffmpeg, and then opencv the file created by ffmpeg

Comment: @road_to_quantdom Could you share the ffmpeg solution you found? Would love to do the same!

Answer (score 1):

Both ffmpeg and ffplay worked fine for me, no rebuild necessary.  On MacOS I just did:

```
brew install ffmpeg
ffplay -rtsp_transport tcp "rtsps://..."
```

Fill in the huge stream URL.  Note the quotes, there was something about the URL without quotes that zsh didn't like. Alternatively to save the stream to a file

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel fatal -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsps://..." -acodec copy -vcodec copy /path/to/out.mp4
```

You could use different options with ffmpeg to transform the stream to something other than rtsps for consumption by some other application.

Interestingly, despite the API telling me this:

```
  "maxVideoResolution": {
    "width": 640,
    "height": 480
  },
```

this is the info from ffplay:

```
  Metadata:
    title           : SDM
  Duration: N/A, start: -0.110000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1600x1200 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 15 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
```

Indicating 1600x1200, not sure why maxVideoResolution isn't actually the max resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying with ffmpeg, however you may need to build it from source.

If you're having trouble with ffmpeg, you can modify the ffmpeg source to increase `control_uri` (in `libavformat/rtsp.h`) size from 1024 to 2048, and recompile. Then ffmpeg should be able to play the RTSPS streams.

Comment: I have got it working with `ffmpeg`. I have a question though. I would like to do two things.

1) copy the stream over ( which I have figured out how to do )
2) process the stream in real-time frame-by-frame ( or at least some frame-rate of it)

Would I be able to that in one-step? Or would I have to create a `ffmpeg` pipe for copying the stream, and also one for saving image frames?